# How to handle POST request in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my ReactJS app running in http://localhost:3000/. I am receiving below form data to my React page as a POST request

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
  Employee Id: <input type="text" name="eid"><br>
  Department Id: <input type="text" name="did"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My react app should be able to handle this POST request and render the UI as below

```
<h1>{eid}</h1>
<h1>{did}</h1>
```

I am able to handle GET request using react router but struggling to handle POST request. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

That is not possible if your React app is static(not server side rendered).
When you send some POST request to your react app, nginx(or other server) will not allow that kind of action(you cannot post to static files)
Even if you bypass that restriction, react script will not have any data from your POST request, because nginx will process your request and return just a html with react script to you

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like php.. you need to have something like backend (node or php to pass the data) or even some site to accept the request..

Answer (score -3):

First, you need maybe some theoretical view:

https://pusher.com/tutorials/consume-restful-api-react

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

---

- You should firstly save data
- You save them to the state
- You display them in the part where it is rendered

To download data from api **(GET)**- you don't do it directly in form - you only use either **ComponentDidMount** or **UseEffect**.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(ApiURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ planets: res }))
      .catch(() => this.setState({ hasErrors: true }));
  }
```

---

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      ApiURL,
    );
    setData(result.data);
  });
```

---

To send data to api **(POST)**- It's complicated - you need information about **client-server** communication

Straight from the React docs:

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is an external application called http://example.com will redirect to my http://localhost:3000/ with POST request. I can handle POST request in Node/Express. Is there any similar way in React page?

Comment: Yes, if you send it by fetch from React, you can handle it in node.js on backend site, and do with this data whatever (send do database, mutate etc.)

Comment: How do i forward these POST inputs from react to node.js server?

Comment: Come on chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205536/post-api Can You? or require 20 rep?