# How to fix the error 'Cannot POST /' when navigating from one website to another

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

Sorry for my ignorance, I'm just learning :)
I need to navigate from one website to another by clicking a button. The first website is just an HTML page, while the website I'm navigating to is built with React. I've written code to make this transition while also passing two parameters.

The file is named index.html

```
 <form action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="test">
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="test2">
        <input type="submit" value="Просмотр">
    </form>
```

When I click on the button to go to the website, I see the message "Cannot POST /."
In the network tab, there's a 404 Not Found error, and in the payload, it contains what I sent.
I don't know how to handle this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truly, to navigate to another site (in your case localhost) you don't need to create a form.

You can just use  tag for it.
Here is the example:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/" target="_blank">Просмотр</a>
```

Here I use `target="_blank"` to open this site in a new tab

Comment: But I also need to pass parameters using the POST method.

Comment: Yeah, I see... I'm not sure that it's possible to do it like that. You can't handle POST request which you send from html page in React app. I think to solve this problem you can:
Create a backend which will authorize user and send login and password to backend.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614067/how-to-handle-post-request-in-reactjs